# Check if something is inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

Firstly, I have to deal with a very large array, so I am trying to convert it into a `Set` and then use `has()` method to reduce time instead of using `includes()` on the `Array` itself.

I converted my `Array` into the `Set` and then using has method and the element for which I am trying to look for is there in that set so `has()` should return `true` but it's giving `false` each time.

```js
exports.DoesUserRegistredInThisEvent = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const userId = req.user.id;
  const eventId = req.params.eventId;
  const userCreatingReview = await User.findById(userId);
  newArray = userCreatingReview.registredInEvents;
  const newSet = new Set(newArray);
  const bool = newSet.has(eventId);
  console.log(newArray); // => ["60982947e2fe4e4eef70fcf3","609270942709952ebb6de50f"]
  console.log(newSet); // => { 60982947e2fe4e4eef70fcf3, 609270942709952ebb6de50f }
  console.log(eventId, typeof eventId); // => 60982947e2fe4e4eef70fcf3 string
  console.log(bool); // => false
  if (bool) {
    next();
  }
  else {
    return next(
      new AppError('User must be registred in this event to perform this action.', 400)
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Show what `typeof eventId` returns.

Comment: Running a modified example of your code, using the values that are "printed" via your comments, the `bool` variable resolves to `true`.

Comment: Performance wise, I doubt you'll gain that much for one single search. The set constructor has to iterate all of the entries inside the array. If anything for one single search this might get you worse results.